# Circular dotted Progress Bar like windows in android

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar

I want to make custom circular dotted progress bar like we have in the windows.

[image]  [image]  [image]  [image]

i am able to make simple rotatory progress bar but not the similar one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have searched for two minutes on google and see what i get.

https://github.com/DamanSingh4321/ProProgressViews?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=5454

https://github.com/81813780/AVLoadingIndicatorView

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3997

Comment: i have seen all those links, but want it exact likes the windows one.

Answer (score 1):

you could try the following library, and I would really recommend that you extract only the progress animation you need as there is no need to have all that animation code inside your app when you don't need it

https://github.com/81813780/AVLoadingIndicatorView